# How to Get the SPUser having FullControl from SPWebApplication

Tags: sharepoint

I require to get the user , which is added in CA on Web Application with Full Control. Please note I do not want the users from SPWebObject , as WebApplication can contain many site collections, so I want to get or verify the user rights of a specific user given rights directly through central admin.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to use the [SPWebApplication.Policies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.sppolicycollection) property for your Web app. I'm sure this could be done more efficiently, but this is what I tried that seemed to work:

```
        System.Uri uri = new Uri("http://sp");
        SPWebApplication webApplication = SPWebApplication.Lookup(uri);
        SPPolicyCollection policyCollection = webApplication.Policies;
        SPPolicyRoleCollection policyRoles = webApplication.PolicyRoles;

        foreach (SPPolicy p in policyCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", p.DisplayName, p.UserName);
            foreach (SPPolicyRole pr in p.PolicyRoleBindings)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("     {0} - IsAdmin: {1}, FullControl: {2}", 
                                   pr.Name, 
                                   pr.IsSiteAdmin, 
                                   pr.GrantRightsMask == SPBasePermissions.FullMask);
            }
        }
```